# Extracting a template image matrix from different image matrices -python -opencv

Tags: python, opencv, matrix

I am new to python programming, the point is that I want to extract exactly the same matrix or minimum different co-matrix in RGB and grayscale image matrices.
If I am processing with nested for loop methods it had to compute the whole matrix at a rate O(n2).

I am providing the pseudo code for the above problem:-

`import cv2
     def matrix_extract(rgb,gray,template):
         rgb = cv2.imread("RGB.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
         template =cv2.imread("template.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
         gray = cv2.imread("Gray.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR) #Already gray scaled image
         length,width,dim=rgb.shape
         linear_matrix=gray.shape
         for i in rgb:
             for j in rgb:
                 if template_found[i,j]== rgb[i,j]:
                    rgb[i,j]=0,0,0`

The thing is that I want to black the area that is included in the original image matrix for the given template matrix. Thanks for help.

Comment: What is `template_found` ? Also attach various input images and expected output ?

Comment: template_found is just the template matrix that is found in the original image matrix.

Comment: Here is a small [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) for your problem

Comment: Sorry this is not meant for matrix comparision between different matrices. Look the template matching return a gray scale image what if I have to process it in the rgb?